# Textures Segmentation

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-image

I need to segment different textures on image without AI or Machine Learning methods, based only on `opencv2` or `skimage` (of course python, numpy, etc.).

Image:

[image]

Ground truth:

[image]

This is how the solution should look like:

[image]

I have already tried a lot of everything: watershed algorithm + clustering KMeans (possible to use), morphological operators, Gaussian blur but still cannot find a good solution since I don't have an idea how to do it. If you have ever encountered with the same problem, please let me know. All images are black and white. If you want to get any code from me - let me know too.

UPD1:

Here you can find other examples: https://mosaic.utia.cas.cz/index.php?act=comp_imgs&bid=4&sort=2&dir=0&nt=-2&ndl=-1&alg=-1&ver=&f1=0&f2=-1&f3=-1&f4=-1&vis=1&hr=0&dyn=0

Here is my Google Colab notebook where I try to write my own solution: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10PtPfBArM0AgDPKHYY7tLwozpaZZho3I?usp=sharing

Comment: Please share any code that shows the work you've already done. Also, how do you know what the solution looks like and why is it different from the ground truth?

Comment: These are all useful tools that you can combine some of these methods to segment textures in black and white images using Python with OpenCV and scikit-image. First, apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise and make texture boundaries more distinct. Then, use Canny edge detection to find edges in the image. Edges can often correspond to texture boundaries. Apply morphological operations like dilation and erosion to enhance texture boundaries and separate regions. Use connected component analysis to segment the image into different regions. Finally, you can color-code them on the original image.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I just updated the question, please check it out. Thank you.

Comment: none of the suggestions in that second comment will lead anywhere. it's probably even AI-generated. -- you want to research "texture analysis". you need features that differentiate those textures. some of that may involve laplacian filters, bandpass filters, multiscale pyramid schemes, or something really simple such as grayscale morphology to estimate the range between local minimum and maximum.

Comment: Could you provide a code example which could help me? Because now it all sounds like ai generated answer like: "You can do it, just use this that those methods, that thing whatever and it is done"

Comment: See gray level cooccurent matrix (GLCM)at skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops. Also https://github.com/luispedro/mahotas/blob/master/mahotas/features/texture.py